# Abysmal ListView performance on Android ICS

Tags: android, performance

In my primary Activity, I am using ListView to list some data, and have made sure that all I/O intensive works (loading thumbnails) are offloaded to AsyncTask. Indeed when running on Galaxy Nexus, it only takes 0~1 ms for my ListAdapter.getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) to execute. And yet scrolling through the ListView on Galaxy Nexus is very slow, it feels like the screens runs at maybe 10 FPS, and actually feels **slower** than my Nexus One running Android 2.3.6.

If anyone have some performance tips on how to make ListView scrolls more smoothly, either on ICS or pre-ICS devices, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Same problem here, just a normal ListView with images as backgrouns with transparency and cacheColorHint set to transparent. No real performance problems on pre ICS devices but really laggy on the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Yes! I have basically the same set up as you, image as ListView background, which contains ImageViews and TextViews, and cacheColorHint set to transparent. The performance is just... shameful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issue like you, my solution is add android:layerType="software" to listview in the layout file, it simply disables hardware acceleration, without losing full Holo theme.
You can view my code here : https://github.com/mariotaku/twidere 
the file is res/layout/refreshable_list.xml

Comment: The performance is somewhat better, but is only as "smooth" as the same app running on Nexus One with Android 2.3.6. Between dual core of Galaxy Nexus and all the performance tweaks they claimed to have for ICS, this is hugely disappointing.

Comment: I can't use computer now, but you can try set android:layerType to none ( I've not tried, this may not help), also, i found all scrollable view in ics reduced their speed and performance. One thing we only can do is optimize our code, such as reduce view depth, make view change not so often etc. I will try to improve the performance in my project, you may find more solutions in my future changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling hardware acceleration in the manifest

Comment: Try disabling hardware acceleration. Disable HA makes listview scrolling much smoother.